# javascript plugin css conflict

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, webpack

i create JavaScript plugin for do transaction i create my own html from using bootstrap and append form to client website given html element,

*my problem is when my plugin import to client web site style change because of my bootstrap plugin, how  i avoid that css conflict issue.

app.scss

```
$form-feedback-icon-invalid: none !default;
$form-feedback-icon-valid: none !default;

@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
@import "~uikit/dist/css/uikit.min.css";
//.db_styles {
//  @import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
//}

//.dp_uk_style{
//  @import "~uikit/dist/css/uikit.min.css";
//}

.containerElement {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.cardFont {
  font-weight: lighter;
}

.uk-card {
  border-radius: 25px;
}

#preloader {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: visible;
  background: url('../images/loadingLogo.svg') no-repeat center center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.329);
}

#logoName {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 360px;
  color: #012480;
}

/* Absolute Center Spinner */
.loading {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  overflow: show;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

/* Transparent Overlay */
.loading:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: radial-gradient(rgba(20, 20, 20, .8), rgba(0, 0, 0, .8));

  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(rgba(20, 20, 20, .8), rgba(0, 0, 0, .8));
}

/* :not(:required) hides these rules from IE9 and below */
.loading:not(:required) {
  /* hide "loading..." text */
  font: 0/0 a;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
}

.loading:not(:required):after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  margin-top: -0.5em;
  -webkit-animation: spinner 1500ms infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: spinner 1500ms infinite linear;
  -ms-animation: spinner 1500ms infinite linear;
  -o-animation: spinner 1500ms infinite linear;
  animation: spinner 1500ms infinite linear;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75) 1.5em 0 0 0, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75) 1.1em 1.1em 0 0, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75) 0 1.5em 0 0, rgba(255,255,255, 0.75) -1.1em 1.1em 0 0, rgba(255,255,255, 0.75) -1.5em 0 0 0, rgba(255,255,255, 0.75) -1.1em -1.1em 0 0, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75) 0 -1.5em 0 0, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75) 1.1em -1.1em 0 0;
  box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75) 1.5em 0 0 0, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75) 1.1em 1.1em 0 0, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75) 0 1.5em 0 0, rgba(255,255,255, 0.75) -1.1em 1.1em 0 0, rgba(255,255,255, 0.75) -1.5em 0 0 0, rgba(255,255,255, 0.75) -1.1em -1.1em 0 0, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75) 0 -1.5em 0 0, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75) 1.1em -1.1em 0 0;
}

/* Animation */

@-webkit-keyframes spinner {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes spinner {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes spinner {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spinner {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

//.was-validated .form-control:valid, .form-control.is-valid {
//  border-color: #28a745;
//  padding-right: 2.25rem;
//  background-repeat: no-repeat;
//  background-position: center right calc(2.25rem / 4);
//  background-size: calc(2.25rem / 2) calc(2.25rem / 2);
//  background-image: none;
//}
//
//.was-validated .form-control:invalid, .form-control.is-invalid {
//  border-color: #dc3545;
//  padding-right: 2.25rem;
//  background-repeat: no-repeat;
//  background-position: center right calc(2.25rem / 4);
//  background-size: calc(2.25rem / 2) calc(2.25rem / 2);
//  background-image: none;
//}
```

webpack config

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackExternalsPlugin = require('html-webpack-externals-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV;
const JavaScriptObfuscator = require('webpack-obfuscator');
const CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const S3Plugin = require('webpack-s3-plugin');
const HTMLInlineCSSWebpackPlugin = require("html-inline-css-webpack-plugin").default;
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

module.exports = {
    mode: `${env === 'production' ? 'production' : 'development'}`,
    entry: path.join(__dirname, 'app', 'index'),
    output: {
        filename: 'directpayCardPayment.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    node: {
        fs: 'empty',
        net: 'empty',
        tls: 'empty',
    },
    plugins: [
        new Dotenv({
            path: `./.env.${env}`,
        }),
        new HTMLInlineCSSWebpackPlugin(),
        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
            options: {
                postcss: [
                    autoprefixer()
                ]
            }
        })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            include: [
                path.resolve(__dirname, 'app')
            ],
            exclude: [
                path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
                path.resolve(__dirname, 'bower_components')
            ],
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015']
            }
        },
            {
                test: /\.(scss)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'style-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader',
                        options: {
                            plugins: function () {
                                return [
                                    require('autoprefixer')
                                ];
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'url-loader',
                    options: {
                        limit: 8000, // Convert images < 8kb to base64 strings
                        name: 'images/[hash]-[name].[ext]'
                    }
                }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'html-loader',
                    options: {
                        minimize: true
                    }
                }]
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.json', '.js', '.jsx', '.css']
    },
    devtool: `${env === 'DEV' ? 'source-map' : 'hidden-source-map'}`,
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        compress: true,
        port: 5000
    }
};


if (env === 'dev' || env === 'production') {
    module.exports.plugins.push(
        new JavaScriptObfuscator({
            compact: true,
            controlFlowFlattening: false,
            controlFlowFlatteningThreshold: 0.75,
            deadCodeInjection: false,
            deadCodeInjectionThreshold: 0.4,
            debugProtection: false,
            debugProtectionInterval: false,
            disableConsoleOutput: false,
            domainLock: [],
            identifierNamesGenerator: 'hexadecimal',
            identifiersPrefix: '',
            inputFileName: '',
            log: true,
            renameGlobals: true,
            reservedNames: [],
            reservedStrings: [],
            rotateStringArray: true,
            seed: 0,
            selfDefending: false,
            sourceMap: true,
            sourceMapBaseUrl: '',
            sourceMapFileName: '',
            sourceMapMode: 'separate',
            stringArray: true,
            stringArrayEncoding: true,
            stringArrayThreshold: 0.75,
            target: 'browser',
            transformObjectKeys: false,
            unicodeEscapeSequence: true
        }),
        new UglifyJsPlugin({
            uglifyOptions: {
                minimize: true,
                compress: true,
                mangle: true,
                warnings: false,
                ie8: false,
                warnings: false, // Suppress uglification warnings
                pure_getters: true,
                unsafe: true,
                unsafe_comps: true,
                output: {
                    comments: false
                }
            }
        }),
        new CompressionPlugin({
            algorithm: 'gzip',
            test: /\.js$|\.css$|\.html$/,
            threshold: 10240,
            minRatio: 0
        }),
        new S3Plugin({
            // Only upload css and js
            include: /.*\.(css|js)/,
            s3Options: {
                accessKeyId: 'xxxxxxxxxx', // Your AWS access key
                secretAccessKey: 'xxxxxx', // Your AWS secret key
                region: 'us', // The region of your S3 bucket
                ACL: 'public-read'
            },
            s3UploadOptions: {
                Bucket: 'xxxxxxx', // Your bucket name
                // Here we set the Content-Encoding header for all the gzipped files to 'gzip'
                ContentEncoding(fileName) {
                    if (/\.gz/.test(fileName)) {
                        return 'gzip';
                    }
                },
                // Here we set the Content-Type header for the gzipped files to their appropriate values, so the browser can interpret them properly
                ContentType(fileName) {
                    if (/\.css/.test(fileName)) {
                        return 'text/css';
                    }
                    if (/\.js/.test(fileName)) {
                        return 'text/javascript';
                    }
                }
            },
            basePath: `${env === 'production' ? 'live/v1' : 'dev/v1'}`, // This is the name the uploaded directory will be given
            directory: 'dist' // This is the directory you want to upload
        })
    );
}
```

Comment: Look, you can change your css class availability to your html only. Assign a class/id to starting of your html and then reference your css using that. like `#main-content .uk-card`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found solution,
i add scss to prefix

```
.prefixName {
  @import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
  @import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
  @import "~uikit/src/scss/variables-theme";
  @import "~uikit/src/scss/mixins-theme";

  @mixin hook-card() { color: #000; }

  @import "~uikit/src/scss/uikit-theme";
}
```